# Disable Androids image-crunch in eclipse (run as) builds

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build

I would like to disable Androids PNG-crunch when I build and run from Eclipse so that the build process is faster (esp. after clean).

I know that if I place build.xml in project root with custom rule target

```
<target name="-crunch">
</target>
```

then an ant-build outside eclipse will not crunch the PNG's. This however does not stop Eclipse from crunching PNG's

How do I configure the Eclipse build process so clean + run-as in eclipse does not crunch my images? Is it possible?

PS: I use PNGGauntlet to compress images before release, which does a better job that androids crunch, but that's not really relevant for the question, as this question is about development builds inside eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this dirty hack:

1. Remove folder "your.project/bin/res/crunch".
2. Make an empty read-only file with name "crunch" at the same place.

It is just preserves your original PNG files. But I don't sure that it is disables execution of PNG-crunch.